# iterm3 reverse minimal theme compact style

Tags: iterm

When my term updated to its latest version (Build 3.3.0beta1), it removed the titlebar from the window.

[image]

Apparently iTerm's **theme** is now: *minimal*. And the ***default profile window type*** is: *compact*

But I have no way of reversing this. How can I get back my titlebar, with the red green and yellow buttons?

[image]

**====> EDIT**

These are what my **theme** and **default profile window** settings look like.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't iTerm have a forum for their beta testers? Or any documentation on this feature?

Comment: @nohillside I didn't see any mention of how to configure the theme or window type on [iTerm2's](https://www.iterm2.com/) FAQ or Documentation site.

Comment: Preferences can be accessed with "Cmd-,", it's probably in Appearance or Profiles.

Comment: @nohillside Yes, I definitely combed through all those options before posting this question. And that's the dilemma - I've looked at and tried all the options. But none of them allow me to revert the theme or window type. So either i) I missed it, ii) setting those options isn't surfaced in the preferences, or iii) I can't do it. I think it's the first. But I can't find the option.

Answer (score 2):

The settings can be changed in Preferences (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd>).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Now that's interesting, because my dropdown don't contain those options. I'm on version `Build 3.3.0beta1`. What version do you have?

Comment: @Nutritioustim I have the same version :-)

Comment: @Nutritioustim Please contact the developer about this, don't think we can find an answer here.

Comment: 10-4, there's definitely something weird going on. Cheers!